# Reload dynamically JSON of configuration in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js

Is it possible to reload configurations of my project dynamically?

Now the configuration file is minified by NPM build and it is not easy to edit a minified file.

My configurations are in `appConfig.js` and it includes code like this:

```
const appConf = {
    BASE_URL: 'http://demo:1817',
    API_BASE_URL: 'http://demo:1817/api'    
};

export default appConf;
```

In my `index.js` there is code like this:

```
import appConf from "./appConf";

angular.module('app', [])
    .constant('appConf', appConf)
    .run(function(){
        //do something
    });
```

In my service, i use the configuration like this:

```
$http.get(appConf.API_BASE_URL + "/something").then(resp => { 
            //do someelse
        });
```

I would like to edit `appConfig.js` with new URL of API without running NPM build.

I want do this because in demo environment the URLs will be changed often.

Answer (score 0):

Its very difficult and not recomended to edit the minimized files in angular2. 
Get base url and use it instead saving in config. Please Try like any of below.
For Angular2 below is code

In service add the below method

```
hostUrl() {
      var hostName = window.location.origin;
      return hostName + '/';
  }
```

In ts file use like below

```
this.http.get(this.service.hostUrl() + "/something" {
    //do someelse
    });
```

or

```
import {LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private locationStrategy:LocationStrategy) {
        let currentUrl = this.locationStrategy.path();
        currentUrl = currentUrl.substring(0, currentUrl.indexOf('?'));
        console.log('currentUrl '+currentUrl);
        this.http.get(currentUrl + "/something" {
        //do someelse
        });
}
```

Comment: yes but i'm in angularJS and i need to set differents URL

Comment: Then we can set profiles like dev, stage and prod in pom.xml if we use maven. That will be better to handle this case. If you have no problem of using  maven i will share that piece of code